# A .txt file is weekly updated to a server, i want the uploaded date time from the file on my php site so the user can see if the file is up-to-date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So if you push a button the file would update a database so the user want the know if the database is up-to-date. I want to know when the file is uploaded to the server
I tried

```
<?php
   if (file_exists(CUR_EXAMPLE_FILE)) 
    {
       echo date ("d-m-Y H:i", filemtime(CUR_EXAMPLE_FILE));
    }
?>
```

but that echos the time you push the button to sync the file.

Comment: _“but that echos the time you push the button to sync the file”_ – and what  do you expect/want instead …?

Comment: I want to know when the file is uploaded to the server. So you know witch file you upload if you push that button. You can push that button but if the file on the server is not up to date you still not have the right database

Comment: There are three basic timestamps when it comes to files - creation time, modification time, and access time. If the modification time (that would be set when an existing file is changed, overwritten with new data) is not what you want - then what do you want instead? We don’t know how your upload/sync process works - so if there is anything involved there that would make the modification time unusable for your purpose, then we might first of all need more info on how that process actually works/what it does.

Comment: I need creation time

Comment: Well then use `filectime` ...

Comment: Tried it just returns the same time as filemtime

Comment: Well then either your file system does not record these times properly, or your sync process does something we don’t know about.

Comment: No cause on the server the time stamp from last modified is different then the filectime and filemtime.